# React return Outlet component when I use render in route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to use react-router with props id but it gave me this info:

> `Matched leaf route at location "/some-12" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.`

I'm using "react-router-dom": "6" and "react": "^17.0.2"

````
//example Routes
import {Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
function App()
return(
   <>
   <Routes>
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />}/>
      <Route exec={true} path="/something" element={<Something/>}/>
      <Route exact={true} path="/something-:id"
             render={(props) => {
             <Some id={props.match.params.id} />;}}
       />
      <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />}/>
   </Routes>
   </>```
````

```
//example Some
export default function Some({ id }) {
    return(
       <>
          <p>Some with id: {id}
       </>
    )}
```

Where I did mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` version 6 the `Route` components render all the routed components on the `element` prop and there are no longer any route props, i.e. no `history`, `location`, or `match`.

Render the `Some` component on the `element` prop and use the `useParams` hook to access the `id` route match param. If `path="/something-:id"` doesn't work then try making the `id` its own path segment, i.e. `path="/something/:id"`.

```
function App()
  return(
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />}/>
        <Route path="/something" element={<Something/>}/>
        <Route path="/something-:id" element={<Some />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />}/>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

...

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Some() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return(
    <>
      <p>Some with id: {id}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you missed a return statement in your element prop.

```
<Route exact={true} path="/something-:id"
             render={(props) => {
             return <Some id={props.match.params.id} />;}}
       />
// or

<Route exact={true} path="/something-:id"
             render={(props) => <Some id={props.match.params.id} />;}/>
```

Note: Upon further research, the render prop has been removed in v6. You should use element instead and fetch the `:id` as per [Drew Reese's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70438994/1647200)